# How many endings are there in dishonored? (SPOILERS)

Tags: dishonored

So, I just finished dishonored with a high chaos level, and got two different endings, in one I saved Emily, she ruled as empress and I guess cured the plague? The other, Emily died, the rat plague killed almost everyone, and was not stopped. So I was wondering, (before I play the game again for nothing) are there more than two endings? And if you know, how do I get them?

Comment: Yup, the other post answered my question, I will definitely be starting over again... I did try, but second level I killed 30 guys... didn't think it would work haha.

Comment: Sadly it is only the ending and rats that your morality affects.  You can probably enjoy the ending just as much on YouTube, if that's what you want.  Obviously if you want to earn it, the low kill play through will naturally be harder.